# Python: Guessing a number is User's mind

Tags: python

I am stuck on a question from my Introduction to Python course. I have to write a code wherein the user keeps an integer in their mind, and the computer guesses. If the user's number is higher than the computer's guess, the user types "+", and the computer guesses higher. If the user's number is lower, the user types "-", and the computer guesses lower numer. If the computer guesses correctly, the user types "y", and the program ends.

Use the builtin function "input" to get a text from the user. If the user types anything other than "+", "-", or "y", the function should throw an exception.

Your function should take no arguments and return nothing.

I have to write the code in python.

*The problem I am facing is that after checking for the input the first time, how to change the range and make the user enter their response again. I have just started coding, so please forgive me if it is a very basic question.*

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to show your work and where you're stuck. Unfortunately, as written, this is off-topic. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem you have and here is my solution for it:

```
import random


low = 1
high = 100

int(input("Enter the number for computer to guess: "))


while low != high:
    guess = low + (high - low) // 2
    high_low = input(f"Computer guess is: {guess} \n "
    f"Press (H) for  higher, (L) for lower and (C) for correct: ").casefold()

    if high_low == "h":
        low = guess + 1

    elif high_low == "l":
        high = guess - 1

    elif high_low == "c":
        print(f"I got it the number is {guess}")
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter h, l or c")
else:
    print(f"Your number is {low}")
```

Here I was using Binary Search algorithm with formula: guess = low + (high - low) // 2. To be more clear, what this formula does it starts of with guessing the mid point between high and low values. If we are told to guess higher that must mean our answer must be between 50 - 100. So the lowest it can be is 51 and that is our new lowest value for the range the mid point now becomes 51+(100-51)//2 (answer from this calculation is 75.5 integer division rounds down) so the result is 75. And If we are told now to guess lower that means answer must be somewhere between 51 and 75, so we know the answer is less than 75, the mid point now becomes 50+(75-51)//2
which is 62 and so on continues with that pattern. You can change H with +,  L with -, and C with y and you will get your solution. I hope you find this useful :).

Answer (score -1):

There are several solutions here, and some are more sophisticated than others.

The simplest solution in my opinion would simply be something like this (without validations):

```
if user_input == "+":
    number = number + 1
elif user_input == "-":
    number = number - 1
elif user_input = "y":
    print("Number guessed correctly.")
```

Depending on the user input, the program will simply add or subtract 1 from the number. That way, you don't require range checks or anything the like.

Let me know if this approach is acceptable.

Comment: Please don't solve peoples' homework assignments. The OP has only provided the assignment and has shown no work. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for pointing this out, @DavidMakogon